# What's the proper way to get data using Entity Framework so you can navigate through objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a .Net 4.5 MVC 5 database first project that I'm playing around with. There's a data access layer (Entity Framework 6), a business logic layer and the MVC layer.

If I have an object with relationships in the data layer:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Course
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tutor> Tutors { get; set; }
    }
    public class Lecture
    {
        public int LectureID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
    public class Tutor
    {
        public int TutorID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my business logic layer I have a method that gets courses:

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public static IEnumerable<Course> GetCourses()
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            return db.Courses.Include("Lectures").Include("Lectures.Students").Include("Tutors").ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the data using my controller like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var courses = BusinessLogic.GetCourses();
        return View(courses);
    }
}
```

Why is it, when I query my data in the Razor view like this:

```
var numLectures = courses.Lectures.Count;
var numStudents = courses.Lectures.Students.Count;
var tutorName = courses.Tutors.LastOrDefault().Name;
```

I get the application error **System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection**.

I know the connection is disposed after the using statement has finished and that .ToList() will let me navigate the courses object, but how do I navigate the objects inside each course (i.e. lectures, students, tutors etc.)?

Comment: You didn't include students.

Comment: Also, none of your navigation properties will load because they are not marked as `virtual`

Comment: I recommend that you include `numLectures` 'numStudents` and `tutorName` as properties on your viewModel that get populated with values in your controller action.

Comment: Is this the proper way of working with MVC (add properties to view models even for use-once properties)? Does this mean I should create a model with courses, students, lectures etc. separated out and then in the controller populate the model parameters for lectures, students etc. and then pass the model to the view?

Comment: @SamStanojevic thanks for pointing that out. I don't understand why the code in question would throw this exception though if it wasn't trying to lazily load *something* after the context has been disposed of.

Comment: Seems a strange and unnecessary amount of work when you have Entity Framework and LINQ.

Comment: Have I missed something? As the `courses` is collection of `Course` it couldn't has property `Lectures`.You should use something like `courses.SelectMany(c => c.Lectures).Count;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because one (or more than one) property that you are calling in your View is (are) not included in your query. Make sure you are including all the navigation properties you need in the view. Try with this query:

```
  using (var db = new MyEntities())
  {
    return db.Courses.db.Courses.Include(c=>c.Lectures.Select(l=>l.Students)).Include(c=>c.Tutors‌​).ToList()
  }
```

If you need to add another relative property that you use in your View, then add another `Include` call for that property.

Another thing, when you need to eager load two levels (like `Lectures.Students`), you don't need to add a `Include` call for each level, with the call that you do for the second level is enough to include both. Could be this way:

```
.Include("Lectures.Students") // as you did it
```

Or:

```
.Include(c=>c.Lectures.Select(l=>l.Students))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation properties need to be declared as `virtual`:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Course
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tutor> Tutors { get; set; }
    }
    public class Lecture
    {
        public int LectureID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
    ...
}
```

When these lazy loadable properties are not marked as `virtual`, the EF dynamic proxies cannot override them and you will never be able to navigate from one entity to a (set of) another.

Another bit of advice: use the strongly-typed `.Include` when eager loading:

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public static IEnumerable<Course> GetCourses()
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            return db.Courses
                .Include(x => x.Lectures.Select(y => y.Students))
                .Include(x => x.Tutors)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helps. Thank you! I was getting context errors in other parts of the application where I was querying objects based on their parent or ancestor properties. Using .Include() and .Select() for all relationships fixed the problem.